# Is set-then-query a sensible way to detect command completion over SCPI?

Tags: serial-port

I'm using a SCPI device over RS-232. I have a number of situations where I want to know that a command has completed before continuing. What seems sensible to me is to end with a query to force the device to send a response line after everything is done, something like the following:

```
:volt 12.34;volt?
```

It is my understanding that `volt?` executes strictly after `volt 12.34` and thus, when I get the response line for `volt?`, I'll know that the voltage has been set. I can also check the response value as a sanity check.

Does this approach acheive what I want? Should the response value always correspond to the value I put in (if it was a valid value)? Is there a better way to do this that I'm not seeing?

(I would have used a `SCPI` tag, but it does not seem to exist.)

Answer (score 0):

`*OPC?` is a query returning 1 when the last operation completed, so:

```
:volt 12.34;*OPC?
```

would return `1` only after the operation has completed.

But if you want to make sure what `volt` is, you still need to query it (for example if you gave out of range voltage. I know some devices might still return 1 for the *OPC but leaving voltage as it is / nearest possible value)